# Catching an AJAX error from a post request (422)

Tags: ajax, shopify

I have the following Ajax but it needs to handle a `422` error being returned (which means **Out of Stock**). I've tried a few ways around but it error's and refuses to `POST` stating:

`Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 422 ()`

I'm unsure how to catch the `422` error and return something to the user displaying that it's out of stock.

```
      Shopify.moveAlong = function() {
        // If we still have requests in the queue, let's process the next one.
        if (Shopify.queue.length) {
          var request = Shopify.queue.shift();
          var data = 'id='+ request.variant_id + '&quantity='+request.quantity_id;
          $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/cart/add.js',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: data,
            success: function(res){
              Shopify.moveAlong();
            },
            error: function(){
              // if it's not last one Move Along else update the cart number with the current quantity
              if (Shopify.queue.length){
                Shopify.moveAlong()
              }
            }
          });
        }
        else {
          window.location.href = "/cart";
        }
      };
      Shopify.moveAlong();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I've tried a few ways around but it error's and refuses to POST.

What I have understood is, you are seeing this error in Browser console. It cannot be prevented, but it does not mean that you request is not going through. The POST request is recieved by Shopify and a response with status 422 is sent, so that is treated as an error (Non 2xx response codes are treated as error).

To handle the error and display error message, adapt the code accordingly. Check updated code and code comments.

```
Shopify.moveAlong = function() {
    // If we still have requests in the queue, let's process the next one.
    if (Shopify.queue.length) {
        var request = Shopify.queue.shift();
        var data = 'id=' + request.variant_id + '&quantity=' + request.quantity_id;
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/cart/add.js',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: data,
            success: function(res) {
                Shopify.moveAlong();
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                // Check status code
                if (jqXHR.status === 422) {
                    // display error wherever you want to  
                    console.log(jqXHR.responseText);
                }
                // if it's not last one Move Along else update the cart number with the current quantity
                if (Shopify.queue.length) {
                    Shopify.moveAlong()
                }
            }
        });
    } else {
        window.location.href = "/cart";
    }
};
Shopify.moveAlong();
```

[AJAX Error Docs](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)